# knockout binding to partial view and jqueryui dialog

Tags: knockout.js

My html looks something like this:

```
<div id="div-details">
    ...
    <div title="Edit" class="edit-pop">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I am doing the binding:

```
var productVM = new ProductViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(productVM, document.getElementById('div-details'));
```

I have to pass the second parameter, as there are some third party code (we don't have control over) above and below div-details, and they use knockout too.

Problem is the edit popup dialog is moved to the bottom of the page, so it is not inside div-details anymore. And the knockout bindings for edit doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code responsible for the problem (i.e. inserting the dialog markup into the DOM). Without an [mcve] it's not really feasible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without your viewModel code,i could guess your question is:

- you have put your "product edting" code inside your "productVM"
- when "div.edit-pop" move out,your binding won't work anymore.

so the solution i suggest is:

- split your edit logic into another model "editModel"
- bind "editModel" with the pop div